# PHP Code protection on Apache results in permission forbidden

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security

I have a Raspberry Pi device running apache. I have tried implementing the code for a small login page that has a in-house made session management supported by MySQL database.

Here is the index.php

```
<?php
include_once 'include/dbmember.php';
include_once 'include/dblogin_attempts.php';
include_once 'include/session.class.php';
include_once 'include/functions.php';


$session=new session();
$session->start_session("SMARTHOMESESSION",false); // TODO CHANGE WHEN SSL HITS

// No need to check login here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Smart Home Login: Credentials first please</title>
    <!-- Need to import styles/main.css and find some css -->
    <!-- http://designscrazed.org/css-html-login-form-templates/ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/loginform.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sha512.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['error']))
{
    echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
}

?>
<div class="login-block">
 <form action="include/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form,this.form.password);" />
 </form>
</div>

<?php  
if (check_login_status($mysql_member))
{
    $user=preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+/", '', $_SESSION['username']);
    echo '<p>Currently logged in as '. htmlentities($user) . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Do you want to change user? <a href="include/logout.php">Log out</a>.</p>';
}
else
{
    echo "<p>Currently logged out.</br>Please login to Continue</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**One big issue here is when i try to provide credentials i get**

> You don't have permission to access /include/process_login.php on this server.

My include directory has .htaccess file and in it

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
```

And i cannot access the process_login.php (Which has no HTML content - its job is just to check the login and redirect if good credentials are provided)

On this link (Which is as close as i can get to a similar question)
[protect php includes (with htaccess?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923431/protect-php-includes-with-htaccess)
It says:

> So, in short:
>       You can put an .htaccess with Deny from all in your PHP include directories. 
>   PHP's include directive does not go through Apache, so it won't care. 
>   Ideally, you don't even put your PHP include directories under your document root at all.
>       You can not do this for JavaScript, as JavaScript access goes through Apache (just like .html, .png, etc. access).

I am doing that (setting an action to an include directory BUT that failed!)
How do i solve that?

My configuration file for apache for the include directory

```
<Directory /var/www.website.com/include>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Also i have a 
protected_page.php with HTML embedded.

Also how come i can use that since i read somewhere that php on apache is passed to directly to the PHP engine and we get only the echo outputs 
But people seem to be using HTML inside php ? (Is that even true? In that case how does AddHandler directive figures out what needs to be shown)

*Can someone explain to me where my logic is failing me on the subject of php file protection and engines on Apache and how come i'm producing a forbidden page where one is not expected.*

Comment: Your form action is `include/process_login.php`, and that means _the browser_ will send a request to that address when the form is submitted – but you have denied all HTTP access to anything inside that directory, so of course you get a 403 here.

Comment: _“But people seem to be using HTML inside php ?”_ – and what about that surprises you – especially considering that you are doing exactly that yourself in your code you have shown already …? http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: It surprises me because it was said that because of the AddHandler directive the client sees just the echo output , yet we have not outputted our HTML with echo command and it is still visible to us. So how can i fix it the 403 and yet make process_login not visible/accessible AND is that possible ?

Comment: Thanks for the URL i upvoted you, it helped allot to understand. So basically we escape the PHP and the HTML part gets ignored by the PHP engine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache v2.4, try changing this in all your *.conf files of Apache :

Instead of

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

(Order allow,deny  and Allow from all is deprecated since V2.4)

Put :

```
 Require all denied
```

If you are not using V2.4 or higher of Apache, then it is a problem with your file/folders permission. Open a terminal, navigate to the folder just before your /include/process_login.php . (CD /yourwebPath/) .

Then, do a

```
sudo chmod 775 include -R 
sudo chown -R root:root include
```

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec  2 23:01 include
 I don't think thats the issue because just the w flag on the group is missing on the include directory. And this is the current ls -la

Comment: Doesn't work - On RPi Apache is 2.2 and chmod doesn't fix the problem.
I ordered Deny,Allow and not vice verca